# Why won't my web page display Google Charts chart?

Tags: html, blackberry, google-visualization

I create a little web page that will be used for BB's. All works except for when I try to display an image using Google Charts. All works as expected on the emulator but the chart images do not work on the physical device. Below is the URL I am using in my image tag.

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=740x200&chf=bg,s,ffffff|c,s,ffffff&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|1:|14000|15000|16000|17000|18000|19000|20000|21000|22000|23000&cht=lc&chd=e:eQb5avaZYOfZmMuO0a4v6N7Z8F9D9M9I8r625k3T2Iwgq7ih,e4eQeIdhdQdAcxc4cPcCb4bebCbAa-ayaWaFaHZsZDY8Y6Z3aLaEadaEZsZoXiXiXpXMXAXIXSXTXeXNXGW8XUW8W7XBXHWmWGWdWeWCWPWjW0WwWjWzXAXbX9YZY3ZLZ4aFa2bUbydKd0egetffgkg8hxibjqkSlLl4m5oRpepip8__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________&chdl=Pre-Dispatch|Dispatch&chco=7DA8CA,92DC6D&chls=3,2,0|3,2,0&chxs=0,000000|1,000000&chg=-10,-100
```

What am I missing?

I did not put an OS or BB version because I cannot get it to work on 5-6 different devices with different versions.

Thank you.

Comment: That's the odd thing. It works if I access it directly from my BB browser. But it will not work if I put it on my web page using the <img> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternatively if the above doesnt work then you will need to get the image. when on the link, right click it, save picture as or you can take this:

[image]

put the image name inside the image tags which will look something like this:

```
<img src="images/chart.png" />
```

then upload via ftp etc etc and you should be done.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. Thank you.

Comment: This could help for static charts, which I suppose the asker was using, but what about generating dynamic images from a php script or the like?